# How strong would diamond armour be?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, minerals

In Minecraft, you can make a set of highly rare diamond armour. If one were to make a set of diamond armour in real life, exactly as portrayed in the game, where 1 square pixel is equal to 1/10th of a meter squared. How strong would this armour be against conventional weapons?

Comment: How thick, in pixels, is diamond armor?

Comment: There are quite some questions on diamond armors. Please check for duplicates. One could be this https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/40532/30492

Comment: "Conventional weapsons" means non-nuclear weapons in general? Weapons are ultra situational, that's why there are so many. There is no standard weaponry. Sadly, when it comes to fighting, you have to get really specific or any answer is mostly useless blabbering

Comment: Let's assume that the armour is pretty strong and would withstand blows without damage to itself. Would *you* survive? Because few people with clubs can rattle you pretty good inside. Kinetic energy from projectiles can also affect you, without affecting the armour. At best, it seems you'd be in a walking coffin as it's a matter of time before you're dead from internal bleeding and other damage from being thrown against a (sort of) indestructible wall repeatedly. There is also the matter of stuff like poison.